# How to Increase a Iframe's Dimention clicking a Button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to increase the iframe's width clicking the "+" Button. But It doesn't works.

```
<iframe id="chkframe" src="" height="500" width="250" onchange="getsize()"></iframe>
</br>
<button onclick="pluswidth()" title="Increase Width">+</button>
<script>
    function pluswidth(){
        var framewidth = documen.getElementById('chkframe').width;
        var frame = document.getElementById('chkframe');
        var math = framewidth + 1;
        frame.width = math;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo ---> documen. in first line of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Used This and got Perfect Result,

```
function incrementvaluewidth()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('chkframe').width);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('chkframe').width = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for iframe:

```
style="height:500px;width:250px"
```

instead of using height and width attributes.

Then use:

```
var framewidth = document.getElementById('chkframe').style.width;

frame.style.width = math + "px";
```

Comment: "500px" or only "500"? will 500px will calculate via JS?

Comment: when you write height="500", 500 is already the height in pixels - see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp

Comment: No, The Height is in pixels. Like only "500" But when I increases the height using javascript by only 1 pixel, It appears to be "5001" instead of "501"